# How strong is my php file upload security?

Tags: php

I would like to have a check whether an uploaded file sent via email and not saved in the DB, allow only the following extensions.

Is this something secure?

```
$allowed =  array('pdf','doc');
$filename = $_FILES['video_file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: If you are devious or so inclined you can have a file uploaded with any extension.

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't (a file could have two extensions : `image.php.jpg`).

If you are planning to upload only images, one good thing is to try to get image size with `getimagesize` and remove it from temp folder if it returns `false`

Comment: Where is this "temp folder" located at ?
Basically I will send only pdf and doc files (i am updating my code)

Comment: If you are planning to upload pdf and docs then don't use this code (pdf don't have sizes as images). Check file mime type, and be sure to store them where they can't be interpreted using apache. About image temp folder, it's usually `/tmp`. If you want more security you may as well create a whitelist of IP adresses allowed to upload, or add a login module before your upload

Comment: I use the mail function to send it to the email. I made a search in my cPanel for the uploaded files using their names but not found